# in javascript validation i have to click submit button twice

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function validaterole(role)
{
    if(role.value==="select")
    {
        var x="select your role";
        document.getElementById("role").innerHTML=x;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("role").innerHTML="";
        return true;
    }
}

function validatepwd(pwd)
{
    //var pwdchecker=/^([A-Za-z0-9]{8,8})$/;            
    //var pwdchecker=/^([A-Z]{1,}[a-z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}(@|#|$))$/;
    var pwdchecker=/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[$@#]).{8,12}$/;

    if(pwd.value===""){
        x="pls enter your password";
        document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML=x;
        return false;
    }
    else if(pwd.value.length < 7 || pwd.value.length > 12){
        x="password length should be 8 to 12";
        document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML=x;
        return false;
    }
    else if(pwd.value.match(pwdchecker))
    {
        x="";
        document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML=x;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        x="password should contain atleast one<br>uppercase and one lowercase<br> alhabets and one number<br>and one special characters($@#)";
        document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML=x;
        return false;
    }
}

function validateemail(email)
{
    var emailchecker=/^([A-Za-z0-9.]{5,30})\@([A-Za-z]{2,13})\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    if(email.value==="")
    {
        x="pls enter your email";
        document.getElementById("em").innerHTML=x;
        return false;
    }
    else if(email.value.match(emailchecker)){
        x="";
        document.getElementById("em").innerHTML=x;
        return true;
    }
    else{ 
        x="Invalid email";
        document.getElementById("em").innerHTML=x;
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="login" name="log" method="post" onsubmit="return (validateemail(document.log.email) && validatepwd(document.log.pwd) && validaterole(document.log.role))">

    <a href="Registration.jsp"><p align="right">New User</p></a>

    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>E-Mail
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" onblur="validateemail(document.log.email)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><span id="em"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PassWord</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="pwd" onblur="validatepwd(document.log.pwd)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><span id="pw"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Role</td>
            <td>
                <select id="sel" name="role" onblur="validaterole(document.log.role)">
                    <option value="select">Select</option>
                <option value="principal">Principal</option>
                <option value="hod">Hod</option>
                <option value="staff">Staff</option>
                <option value="student">Student</option>
            </select>
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td align="left"><span id="role"></span></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

my second issue with onfocusout or onblur event,whenever i click submit button the form is not submitted and on the second click,form submitted..
i need to do this in single click. hlp me if u haave a solution

Comment: Try to call all three function into single function.that funtion use into submit  click event.I thing this can solve your problem

Comment: nope i need to validate individual textboxes as well as using submit button

Comment: look fine to me check here https://plnkr.co/edit/fuopiqYU3uJZBBIhAlLe?p=preview

Comment: when i click submit button, i need to validate all  of the textboxes

Answer (score 0):

Use a single function on submit button and call other functions from that function.

Comment: the problem is span tag i give width to that span cells ..works great